# Можно ли записать в файл число в hex, предворительно не переводя его в строку с помощью sprintf?

Tags: c

Есть число, возможно ли записать его в файл в hex виде, но предворительно не переводить его в строку чперез sprintf?

Comment: Использовать `fprintf`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Без проблем:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n = 255;
    FILE *fout = fopen("1.txt", "w");
    fprintf(fout, "%x", n);
    fclose(fout);
    return 0;
}
```